# Swift Test: Controlling moc api client behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, testing, mocking

I am writing test for my project and declared a remote API client protolcol:

```
public protocol ApiClient {
    func load(completion: @escaping ([Any]?, String?))
}
```

and defined a moc api client that confirms to `ApiClient`:

```
class MocApiClient: ApiClient {
    func loadFlights(completion: @escaping ([Any]?, String?)) {
        // Load a sample JSON file and return it as response
    }
}
```

this way I am able return a response by loading a `JSON` file. This is the happy path of the test. After it I started to think about testing different possible response types and decided that I should be able to alter behaviour of the `MocApiClient` and defined this:

```
enum TestPath {
    case success
    case failure
}
```

and using it with `MocApiClient`:

```
class MocApiClient: ApiClient {

    var path: TestPath = .success

    func load(completion: @escaping ([Any]?, String?) -> Void) {

        switch path {
        case .success:
            completion([...], nil)
        case .failure:
            completion(nil, "error message")
        }
    }
}
```

Doyu think this is a good solution?
Do you have any beter approachs?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems fine if you have just a few simple tests.
However, if you have a relatively complex logic and need to test many positive and negative paths, an alternative to your solution would be creating several different mocking objects, each one having a single purpose.

That way, you'll avoid a massive all-purpose mocking object problem and also will be able to define your mocking objects right inside the tests methods that use them, thus making your tests even more focused and independent.

Something like this:

```
func testSuccessfulResponse() {
    class MockApiClientSuccessfulResponse: ApiClient {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

func testMalformedResponse() {
    class MockApiClientMalformedResponse: ApiClient {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

func testInconsistentData() {
    class MockApiClientInconsistentData: ApiClient {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps and happy unit testing!